# Regex For All Illegal Characters In URL

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a txt file that contains illegal characters. For this reason when I run my program it will crash since the illegal characters are not allowed. I can't print the characters as when I copy and paste they show up as a blank space. In Notepad++ they are showing as "NULL". I was thinking the best solution would be to make a regex of all allowed characters. Now I am new to regex and I used the pipe when creating my regex. This did not work as regex will search for the characters [A-Z] first as an example and if it finds it then move onto the next URL.

As an example a URL could look like this:

> http://www.example/com/folder/topic1/ILLEGALCHARACTER

Now my regex wont clean this, like I said Im a newbie so can't figure this out. The characters that I want to allow are:

```
0-9
A-Z
a-z
­

'
-
–
—
!
"
$
%
&
(
)
*
,
.
/
:
;
?
@
[
\
]
_
`
{
|
}
~
¡
¦
¿
‘
’
‚
“
”
‹
›
¢
£
¥
€
+
<
=
>
±
«
»
×
§
©
®
µ
…
‰
Á
á
À
à
â
Â
ä
Ä
Ã
ã
Å
æ
Æ
Ç
ç
Ð
é
É
è
È
Ê
ê
Ë
ë
ƒ
Í
í
Ì
Î
Ï
ñ
Ó
ó
Ò
Ô
Ö
Õ
Ø
Œ
œ
ß
Þ
™
Ú
Ù
û
Û
Ü
ü
Ý
ÿ
```

The best regex I could find was this:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

This however is not working. I am using a custom duplicate remover and it still crashes. The developer is telling me its because it sees the illegal characters as end of line etc. Would appreciate help on this

The regex language is PERL

Comment: Depending on your language, you could always try to use something like: `(?:\p{ASCII}|[\u2018-\u201F\u2122])+`. You can reference [here](http://unicode-table.com/en) for unicode numbers/ranges you want to include. As a side note, are angled quotes or trademark symbols even allowed in a url?

Comment: Not sure on that to be honest, these are characters developer said should be allowed

Comment: Did you verify what exactly is the "illegal character"? I am afraid that it might be the end-of-line, or `\n` in C and regexes. If this is the case, you might think again how to read the data from the file, rather than complicate your life to sanitize the data afterwards.